# How to Zoom in and zoom out through animation

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-phone-8

I have set of images which are placed in pivot control. I want to zoom in the image to a specific point and then go back to its normal size through animation. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="story">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="img"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                             From="300"
                             To="600"
                             Duration="0:0:2">
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Height="100" Width="100" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    <Image x:Name="img"  Height="300" Width="200" Source="/Assets/10.png"></Image>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Please put some code..What you have tried?

Comment: i use this above code @MayankJain

Comment: This is not What i want @Pradnya Bolli

Comment: Do you want to see the animation when the page is rendered, or when a certain event?

Comment: when a certain event is triggered @user2784555

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, then you should use the Storyboard, EventTrigger and ScaleX Instead of Height to Resize a image.

[Storyboarded and trigger animations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819807.aspx)

Here is one option for the loaded event.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Height="100" Width="100" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    <Image x:Name="img"  Height="300" Width="200" Source="/Assets/10.png">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="ImageScale" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
        <Image.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImageScale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" To="1.5" Duration="0:0:0.7" AutoReverse="True"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImageScale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To="1.5" Duration="0:0:0.7" AutoReverse="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Image.Triggers>
    </Image>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

**first tip:-**

Avoid writing `Resources` into specific control. Instead define all resources into `<Page.Resources>`

Now, if you want to animate some control, then you have to use Scaling property of an element.

Check below code. here, I'm pointing out how to zoom the image on any event handler.

**XAML code of control**

```
<Image x:Name="img" Source="/Assets/image1.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5" >
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform x:Name="compositeTransform"  />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

**Defining Storyborad**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="story">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="compositeTransform"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                         From="0" To="5"
                         Duration="0:0:2" />

        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="compositeTransform"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                         From="0" To="5"
                         Duration="0:0:2" />
    </Storyboard>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

**On any of the event handler**

```
story.Begin();
```